# Adjoint Operator densely defined

Tags: functional-analysis

Reading Brezis Book on Functional Analysis I've seen that it may happen that $T^*$, the adjoint operator of an unbounded operator $T$, is not densely defined even if $T$ is closed.

I am not sure that the same comment remains true if we are working with a closed operator  $T:D(T)\subset H \to H$, where $H$ is an Hilbert Space and, clearly, $D(T)$ is densely defined.

Can anyone prove that every closed operator on Hilbert Space has the adjoint operator densely defined?

Comment: Look Theorem VIII.1 in Reed, Simon's "Functional Analysis".

Comment: It is possible to construct a non closable operator whose adjoint is trivial.